# How to change the y tick label in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

The below code generates a scatter plot.

```
#KNNClassifier_weighted
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(100, 30)) 
xy = np.array([
    (x, y) for x, lst in df_param.items()
    for sublst in lst for y in sublst
])
plt.scatter(*xy.T, s=500,  edgecolors='black', linewidth=3)
plt.title("KNNClassifier: weighted",fontsize=80)
 
# Setting the x and y labels
plt.xlabel("Iteration",fontsize=80)
plt.ylabel("value",fontsize=80)
#labels=["True", "False"]
# Setting the number of ticks
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(df_param)+1, 10),fontsize=34, rotation=90)
plt.yticks(fontsize=45)
plt.xlim(xmin=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]
A sample of the dataframe that is used to generate the plot is

```
{0: [[True], [False], [True], [False], [False], [False]], 1: [[False], [True], [False], [False], [False]], 2: [[False], [True], [False], [False]], 3: [[False], [False], [False]], 4: [[False], [False]], 5: [[False]], 6: [], 7: [], 8: [[False]], 9: [], 10: []}
```

When I try putting the labels in an array and set it as yticks.

```
labels=["True", "False"]
# Setting the number of ticks
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(df_param)+1, 10),fontsize=34, rotation=90)
plt.yticks(labels, fontsize=45)
```

I get the conversion error.

```
ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: ['True', 'False']
```

I want the values in the dataframe to be used as labels.

Comment: Please provide a [simple reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the issue. The data provided is redundant to reproduce the problem

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this myself but something like this may help:

```
plt.yticks([1.0, 0.0], labels, fontsize=45)
```